# Iterate Recursively through matrix

Tags: recursion

Just was wondering does anyone know how to iterate through a matrix recursively from some thing similar structure like this:

```
 function matrixIter(array) {
    
    for(let row = 0; row < array.length; row++){
  
        for(let col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
            console.log(array[row][col]);
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Don't know why you would wanna do it but what you always need for recursion is a base case where the recursion ends, which is quite simple here. How would you iterate through a `1x1` matrix? You just print that one value. Then you can think of how you would reduce the problem  of a `X x Y`down so you end up with a 1x1 matrix at the end and you'll have your solution.

Comment: Just doing it to show I can do things iterative and recursive for all the different data structures